# Calculating values

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Am having a problem in my jquery script to do multiplication

in my script this is the area of problem i have

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".parameter").on("input",function() {
        var num = $('input[name="num"]').val();
        var left = $('input[name="left"]').val();
        var total = num * left %; // 2 x 50000 % = 1000
        var finalr = left - total; // 50000 - 1000 = 49000
      $(".result").text(finalr +" final result"); // prints 49000
    });
})
</script>
```

I want to make calculation and results go to disabled input box automatically as i descried it in html comments

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
#div1, #div2 {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: fit-content;
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  --val: '';
}

#div1::after {
  content: var(--val) ' INX';
  position: absolute;
  left: 3px;
  top: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  pointer-events: none;
  line-height: 20px;
}

#left, #right {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
}

#left {
  color: transparent;
}
</style>
<body>

<p>  
<input type="text"  name="num" class="parameter" placeholder="amo"/> <! --- value set to 2 ---> 
</p>

 <div id="div1">
 <input type="text" id="left" name="left" class="parameter" maxlength="18" /></div> <! --- value set to 50000 --->

<div id="div2">
<input type="text" id="right" name="right" class="result" placeholder="INX" disabled /></div> <! --- 49000 results goes here --->

<script>
document.querySelector('#left').addEventListener('input', function() {
  this.parentElement.style.setProperty('--val', "'"+this.value+"'");
  document.querySelector('#right').value = this.value ? this.value + ' INX' : '';
});
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".parameter").on("input",function() {
        var num = $('input[name="num"]').val();
        var left = $('input[name="left"]').val();
        var total = num * left %; // 2 x 50000 % = 1000
        var finalr = left - total; // 50000 - 1000 = 49000
      $(".result").text(finalr +" final result"); // prints 49000
    });
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And that _"problem"_ is what exactly?

Comment: `num * left %; // 2 x 50000 % = 1000` - What ever "math" that is, it's not the one you learn in school. Fix that syntax error (which the browser should have told you) and your script should work.

Comment: `$(".result")` is an `<input />` element -> `.val()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue is you're trying to use `%` as a percentage. `%` is the [Remainder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) operator.

what you can do is to replace

```
var total = num * left %;
```

with

```
var total = num * left/100;
```

Comment: if ur doing var total = num * left/100; where is the 100 comes from, it has to come from calculation not defining, because i may get random figures which is not left/100;

Comment: @JoeMike _"where is the 100 comes from"_ - It's the correct way for your misplaced `%`. At least that's what we all think it is for -> percentage.

Comment: @JoeMike if you want to know how much is  x percent of a number `num` the calculation would be `num * x%` as you thought. but js doesn't use the `%` operator for percentage.
so calculating `%` would be `num * x/100` since `%` is just dividing the number by 100. e.g: 20% out of 100 is 100*20% = 100*20/100 = 20

Comment: @JoeMike what did you expect and what are you getting? I'll try to help, but regardless you should mark this answer as correct since this was the problem in your code.

Answer (score -1):

try using

```
$(".result").val(finalr +" final result");
```

I haven't checked but I hope it works.